# React CodeMirror is not editable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, codemirror

I am making use of CodeMirror for react. I am referring to the docs but I am **unable to make it editable.**

Here's the code :

```js
import { Controlled as CodeMirror } from 'react-codemirror2';
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript';

const ResponseMappings = () => {
  const [code, setCode] = React.useState('{ name: "Karan" }');
  return (
    <CodeMirror
      value={code}
      options={{
        mode: 'javascript',
        theme: 'material',
        lineNumbers: true,
        readOnly: false,
      }}
      onChange={(editor, data, value) => setCode(value)}
    />
  );
};

export default ResponseMappings;
```

Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two versions of the ReactCodeMirror - Controlled and UnControlled.

In your example, you used Controlled ReactCodeMirror. It means that you need to change the code via state and you need to do it in the `onBeforeChange` event.
Like This:

```
import { Controlled as CodeMirror } from 'react-codemirror2';
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript';

const ResponseMappings = () => {
  const [code, setCode] = React.useState('{ name: "Karan" }');
  return (
    <CodeMirror
      value={code}
      options={{
        mode: 'javascript',
        theme: 'material',
        lineNumbers: true,
        readOnly: false,
      }}
      onBeforeChange={(editor, data, value) => {
        setCode(value);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import CodeMirror from '@uiw/react-codemirror';
import { javascript } from '@codemirror/lang-javascript';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <CodeMirror
      value="console.log('hello world!');"
      height="200px"
      extensions={[javascript({ jsx: true })]}
      onChange={(value, viewUpdate) => {
        console.log('value:', value);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```